# get a data with HTMLagilitypack from a span 2

Tags: c#, html, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to catch some data from a website using HtmlAgilityPack. The data is stored in an object with the property class="vcard-content". But the problem I want to know is there any way to get this data from a specific class with that value, using "Start with" or "Contained.." or some thing like this ?
I want to get only Phone Numbers and Emails

HTML Code :

```
<span>

    <img alt="09122270931" src="../img/profile/icon03.png"></img>

    Phone Number : 09122270931

</span>
<span>

    <img alt="persian8008@yahoo.com" src="../img/profile/icon07.png"></img>

    Email: persian8008@yahoo.com

</span>
```

I use this codes but it returns null value.

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='vcard-content' and contains(text, 'Phone Number :')]/span/text()");
```

and

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='vcard-content' and (starts-with(normalize-space(), '@'))]/span/text()");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this XPath query :

```
"//div[@class='vcard-content']/span[contains(., 'Phone Number :')]/text()"
```

That will search `<div>` element having class attribute value equals 'vcard-content' and having child `<span>` element containing text 'Phone Number :', then select text inside that `<span>`. You can use similar construction to search for `<span>` element containing 'Email :'.